# Is this true about the Jacobian?

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I want to make the assertion that if the jacobian of a function $\mathbb{R^k} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ at a point is $0$, the point must be either a parabolic extremum (local minimum or local maximum) or a saddle point.

My reasoning is, if the jacobian is the 0 matrix then the tangents to the coordinate curves are nonexistent and this can only happen at points of inflexion, which are exhaustively covered by the prior $2$ cases I think.

Am I correct?

Comment: What is your definition of a saddle point in this case? What you're asking about might just be true by definition.

Comment: I am thinking of it geometrically, i.e a point where the principal curvatures are opposite to each other.

Comment: What about $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\mapsto x_1^3$ evaluated at $x=0$?

Comment: I'm not sure that "tangents ... are nonexistent" is really a good way to describe $J=0.$